# Printing PDF using pdf.js

Tags: javascript, pdf, printing, pdf.js

I am embedding a single page PDF in a page using pdf.js and I want to be able to print just the PDF, not the whole HTML page.

Is this possible?

Comment: What browser do you use? I let the `supportsPrinting` method in `viewer.js` return true by default and i can use the print (provided by pdf.js) in chrome.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I finally worked it out.

I can't post my code here, but here's what I did:

I rendered the PDF onto 2 canvases, one small for the thumbnail and one huge for printing (hidden). I then had a print button that opened a new window containing an `img` tag containing the contents of the huge canvas using `toImageURL()`. The `print()` function was called on the new window, followed by `close()` to close it automatically once printed.

This resulted in an almost-full-size print of the PDf, albeit with the usual page no and datestamp from the browser.

Comment: Everything is in my answer. You just need to read the documentation and think a little, rather than blindly copy and paste some code you don't understand.

Comment: I like blind pasting code much more than reading answers which tell me that i should think more myself..

Comment: I never found a toImageURL in the documentation.  I did find a toDataURL() in the documentation.  I used that I got it work well.

Comment: Negative score on accepted answer is weired, that shoudn't happen.

Comment: @ImranZahoor I think people didn't like that I explained what I did rather than just posting the code (which belonged to a client so I couldn't share it anyway)

Answer (score 6):

I had previously loaded a pdf document onto a canvas using pdf.js.

The canvas only contains one page. So This is what worked for me for a single page:

```
  var canvas = document.getElementById('pdfPage');
  var win = window.open('', '', '');
  var html = "<img src='" + canvas.toDataURL() + "'>";
  win.document.write(html);
  win.document.close();
  win.focus();
  win.print();
  win.close();
```

I still need to find out what is needed for multiple pages. If I do, I'll edit this answer.

I have to say this approach is not optimal, because it doesn't print the pdf page "camera ready" or in other words in it's original form. It prints an image of the pdf page. The difference is the margins that should not be there and the header / footer that should not be there, as they are not in the original document. Therefore, I'm going to be looking for an approach that prints it like the pdf.js viewer prints it -- in it's original form with fidelity to the orignal document.

Comment: Did you ever find anything?

Comment: @Jamil, search my answers for pdf. I'm not with that company any more.

Answer (score 3):

We can put following code at the end of **viewer.js** file which will automatically print pdf:

```
(function () {
    function printWhenReady() {
        try{
            if (PDFViewerApplication.initialized) {
                window.print();
            }
            else {
                window.setTimeout(printWhenReady, 3000);
            }
        }catch(ex){
            window.setTimeout(printWhenReady, 3000);
        }
    };

    printWhenReady();
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You might to use Print.js library to print PDF file.

To navigate this url: https://printjs.crabbly.com/

Answer (score 0):

The answer from [JPatel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5761153/jpatel) led me to a solution that works for me.

I got a document management system with version control. If I select a document or a specific version I will get a preview. I want to be able to print the visible preview from a button.

The pdf container is like the following:

```html
<object id="@_pdfPreviewId" type="application/pdf" data="@GetOpenPdfPath()"></object>
```

I use blazor, so `@_pdfPreviewId` is a randomized id and `@GetOpenPdfPath()` returns the download path for the preview file.

So now:

1. I call feed in the new download url into the preview
2. I call the following JS function when the user presses a print button:

```js
async function print(pdfContainerId) {
    var container = document.getElementById(pdfContainerId);
    var pdfWindow = container.contentWindow;

    var app = pdfWindow.PDFViewerApplication;

    while (!(app.initialized && app.downloadComplete)) {
        await delay(1000);
    }

    pdfWindow.print();
}

const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
```

Now the loop loops until the preview is ready and then this beatiful dialog ...

[image: Preview is getting prepared]

... appears